# Solr indexing support for NetCDF files?

Tags: solr, lucene, netcdf

I am brand new to Solr and NetCDF, and am working on a project that is very much out of my realm of expertise. So I don't know where to look for the best information. I currently have an installation setup and for now I am browsing the directories and configuration files to get familiar. Although I found a few resources and tutorials that have given me a general understanding of how to work with Solr, I do not know how to translate this information specific to working with NetCDF.

Are there any guides, books, or resources that provide information specific to my case? Does Solr/Lucene even support NetCDF indexing by itself? I would appreciate any advice/suggestions/input you might have.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know about solr, but for NetCDF You can use standard programs to extract the data for indexing. Tools exist for C, JAVA and Python (You're probably not interested in FORTRAN), so just dump the necessary data to something that can be read by solr and that's it.

Comment: We do actually have these extraction programs on our servers, and certainly we could create a cron job to run translations regularly. However we have a huge database of these files and need some level of disk efficiency. I've looked into Apache Tika which seems promising.